# Flutter: display something when future takes longer than 5sec

Tags: flutter

In my app I have a sign-in page which signs the user in using firebase. I want to display a text (e.g. Please check your connection) if the sign-in takes longer 5sec.

```dart
User _userFromFirebaseUser(FirebaseUser user) {
    return user != null ? User(uid: user.uid) : null;
  }

Future signIn(String email, String password) async {
    try {
      AuthResult result = await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: email, password: password);
      FirebaseUser user = result.user;
      return _userFromFirebaseUser(user);
    } catch (error) {
      print(error.toString());
      return null;
    }
  }
```

What is the best way of doing this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [.timeout(Duration)](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.7.2/dart-async/Future/timeout.html) method.

Above code could then read similar to this:

```dart
Future signIn(String email, String password) async {
  try {
    AuthResult result = await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
        email: email, password: password).timeout(Duration(seconds: 5);
    FirebaseUser user = result.user;
    return _userFromFirebaseUser(user);
  } on TimeoutException catch (e) {
    // TODO
  } catch (error) {
    print(error.toString());
    return null;
  }
}
```